# Why onclick javascript remove not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here's my codes:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        addColor = function(){
            let html = '<div class="row no-gutters">\n'+
                '<div class="col-md-3">\n'+
                '<label for="color_name" class="ml-1">Color name:</label>\n'+
                '<input type="text" id="color_name" name="color_name[]" class="form-control w-auto d-inline">\n'+
                '</div>\n'+
                '<div class="col-md-3">\n'+
                '<label for="color_code" class="ml-1">Color code:</label>\n'+
                '<input type="text" id="color_code" name="color_code[]" class="form-control w-75 d-inline jscolor">\n'+
                '</div>\n'+
                '<div class="col-md-1">\n'+
                '<a onclick="addColor()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>\n'+
                '<a onclick="deleteColor()" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>\n'+
                '</div>\n'+
                '</div>';
            $('#box').append(html)
        };
        deleteColor = function () {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        };
    });
</script>
```

I want to remove the `onclick=deleteColor()` so the link cannot be clicked or `check()` won't be fired. How can I do it with JQuery?

Comment: because $(this) show window object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that inside your `deleteColor`, it don't know what `this` refers to, so do it like this:

```
deleteColor = function(obj) {
  $(obj).parent().remove();
};
```

and

```
onclick="deleteColor(this)"
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  addColor = function() {
    let html = '<div class="row no-gutters">\n' +
      '<div class="col-md-3">\n' +
      '<label for="color_name" class="ml-1">Color name:</label>\n' +
      '<input type="text" id="color_name" name="color_name[]" class="form-control w-auto d-inline">\n' +
      '</div>\n' +
      '<div class="col-md-3">\n' +
      '<label for="color_code" class="ml-1">Color code:</label>\n' +
      '<input type="text" id="color_code" name="color_code[]" class="form-control w-75 d-inline jscolor">\n' +
      '</div>\n' +
      '<div class="col-md-1">\n' +
      '<a onclick="addColor()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus">+</i></a>\n' +
      '<a onclick="deleteColor(this)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times">-</i></a>\n' +
      '</div>\n' +
      '</div>';
    $('#box').append(html)
  };
  deleteColor = function(obj) {
    $(obj).parent().remove();
  };
  
  addColor();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```